# Is this how to use mod_speling?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-speling

I had my VPS host enable mod_speling, but I'm not sure it's working, and just wanted to check with you guys that I've got the right idea about it.

I have URLs on the server like this:

```
https://www.example.com/users/TOMMO/
https://www.example.com/users/JULIE/
```

People that type URLs using all lower case are getting 404 errors, so I figured enabling mod_speling would fix it. This is what I have in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
CheckCaseOnly On
```

Should this be working?

Answer (score 0):

The [mod_speling documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_speling.html) says this of `CheckCaseOnly`:

> When set, this directive limits the action of the spelling correction to lower/upper case changes. Other potential corrections are not performed.

So that sounds pretty much like exactly what you want. If won't attempt to correct: `https://www.mysite.com/users/juliee/` but it will ignore case when you go to `https://www.mysite.com/users/JULIE/`.

But if you're not using mod_rewrite, you *don't* need the `RewriteEngine On` line.